Which servicemanager and binder driver is used in the communication between system and HAL through stable AIDLs
Now, Android system has 3 binder drivers, /dev/binder and servicemanager for system to system, /dev/hwbinder and hwservicemanager for system to vendor HAL, /dev/vendor and vndservicemanager for vendor to vendor. My question is which servicemanager and binder driver is used in the communication between system and vendor HAL through stable AIDLs?
I guess /dev/binder and servicemanager. Right?

Per https://source.android.com/docs/core/architecture/hidl/binder-ipc#vndbinder

Normally, vendor processes don't open the binder driver directly and instead link against the libbinder userspace library, which opens the binder driver.

